# Incorrect <title> tag found by Geb in Grails app

Tags: grails, functional-programming, geb, testlink

The page title is "Page1" (https://github.com/biomq/geb-example-grails/blob/master/grails-app/views/person/page1.gsp#L8), but the Page DSL is checking for a title of "Person List" (https://github.com/biomq/geb-example-grails/blob/master/test/functional/pages/LinkPage1.groovy#L9).

To run tests:
grails -Dgeb.env=firefox test-app functional:

If you edit LinkPage1's title ==~ /Page1/ to the *incorrect* value title ==~ /Person List/ [as it is now, in the repo] while *leaving* Page1 in page1.gsp, the test *passes*! The test failure then occurs further down with 'testLink' "page content not found".

If you edit person/page1.gsp and replace g:link controller="Person" action="page2" id="testLink" ... with a href="/person/page2" id="testLink"... i.e. provide an explicit testLink id, and use testLink { $("#testLink") } in LinkPage1.groovy, the page content not found error persists.

hmmmm...

Answer (score 0):

It should be `to LinkPage1` and not `at LinkPage1` [here](https://github.com/biomq/geb-example-grails/blob/40d18252de0417fb5c25216060a87883b88ad0d6/test/functional/PersonCRUDSpec.groovy#L12) if you want to go to `/person/page1.gsp`. Have a look at [the Book of Geb](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/), the difference between `at()` and `to()` is described there.